Spring-Kafka producer message too slow
I am write an spring-boot application, receive request and has some data process then write data to kafka.
When i take the Stress testing, i find the kafka message deliver is very slow.
The data process logical is like this :

private KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate;


List<Map<String,String>> receive_data = parse(httpRequest);

List<Map<String,String>> processed_data = process(receive_data);

processed_data foreach {
  kafkaTemplate.send();
}


when i check the jstack, i find most thread stack is like this
"qtp1206051975-94" #94 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fe054034800 nid=0x34c waiting on condition [0x00007fdfeb4f2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000788869f80> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2163)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.BufferPool.allocate(BufferPool.java:143)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.RecordAccumulator.append(RecordAccumulator.java:218)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:942)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:865)

My Kakfa Producer config is
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, CompressionType.ZSTD.name);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 60000);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 100);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 10);
    props.put(JsonSerializer.ADD_TYPE_INFO_HEADERS, false);

I has change the buffer.memory from default 32M to 64M or 128M, but still get same result.
The TPS is not increase.
And my spring application is use jetty as web server
i changed the jetty thread
server:
  jetty:
    threads:
      max: 400
      min: 20

can someone help me on this, thanks.
i want improve the application's TPS, now it looks stuck by kafka message deliver speed.

The batch.size is very small, increase it or use the default value with a bigger linger.ms, so it would take that time to batch more records when it is blocked and publish them at once.
Increasing the max.in.flight.requests.per.connection will increase the number of requests in a single connection.
Check the min.insync.replicas value, 2 should be good for a replication factor of 2 or above. With acks all, it will wait for acknowledgements from all the replicas.
Values vary depending on the messages size and desired throughput, I would start with default batch.size, linger.ms=100 and min.insync.replicas=2
